# Create structured JS object based on unstructured JS object

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, data-structures, reduce

I have this js object data:

```
const content = 
  [ { h1 : 'This is title number 1'          } 
  , { h2 : 'Description'                     }
  , { p  : 'Description unique content text' }
  , { h2 : 'Content'                         }
  , { p  : 'Content unique text here 1'      }
  , { ul : [ 
           'string value 1',
           'string value 2'
       ]                       
  , } 
  , { p  : 'Content unique text here 2'      }
  , { h2 : 'CTA message'                     }
  , { p  : 'CTA message unique content here' }
  , { h2 : 'CTA button'                      }
  , { p  : 'CTA button unique content here'  }
  , { p  : ''                                }
  , { h1 : 'This is title number 2'          } 
  , { h2 : 'Description'                     }
  , { p  : 'Description unique content text' }
  , { h2 : 'Content'                         }
  , { p  : 'Content unique text here 1'      }
  , { h2 : 'CTA message'                     }
  , { p  : 'CTA message unique content here' }
  , { h2 : 'CTA button'                      }
  , { p  : 'CTA button unique content here'  }
  , { p  : ''                                }
  ]
```

`h1` indicates a new object, the `ul` is optional

I want to map it to such structure:

```
interface Content = {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  content: any[];
  cta: {
    message: string;
    button: string;
  }
}
```

I am wondering what is the best way of doing that?

I think I have to loop through the items and just populate a new JSON object based on my interface. The first element is always title, then just checking if "description" then the next item is description value.

```
    const json = Content[];
    content.forEach(element => {
    if(element.h1) {
        // add props to new object
        // add object to json array
    }
});
```

I just wonder how wold you create multiple Content objects based on that original content JSON object?

Here is the result I am expecting:

```
json = [
  {
    title: 'This is title number 1',
    description: 'Description unique content text',
    content: [
      {
        p: 'Content unique text here 1',
      },
      {
        ul: [
            'string value 1',
            'string value 2'
        ]
      },
      {
        p: 'Content unique text here 2'
      } 
    ],
   cta: {
      message: 'CTA message unique content here'
      button: 'CTA button unique content here'
   }
  },
  ...
]
```

UPDATE:
Based on comments below I am looking for top down parser solution. The solution should be easily extensible in case if input array will be changed a bit by introducing new unique `h2+p` or `h2+p+ul`, etc elements.

Comment: You're effectively building a parser. Should be relatively simple with a top-down greedy approach.

Comment: @Bergi currently looking into this library https://github.com/brunoimbrizi/array-unflat/blob/main/index.js, thinking of splitting the original array into groups and then use map function. Do you think would it be an optimal path?

Comment: No. That `unflat` function you linked (better known as [`chunk`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8495687/1048572)) works only if each group has the same size, which is not the case with your data. You need to group by other factors. Have you written a parser before?

Comment: @Bergi right i c. Haven't being dealing with flat data like that in js/ts. Can you point out to the right direction? May be there is a lib that can help or a code snippet to look at?

Comment: Maybe https://11l-lang.org/archive/simple-top-down-parsing/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages can help

Comment: @Bergi Oh now I clearly see that I haven't being written any parsers like that before. Found another one here https://github.com/codebox/top-down-parser but not so helpful yet due to my knowledge gap in that area

Comment: Try to find one that doesn't take a grammar as input but one that lets you build rules in code. And you'll need one that takes in an array of elements, not a string.

Comment: Or look at the output (the generated code, not the source code) of a parser generator to get an idea

Comment: Here's some articles that might be more helpful: https://blog.mgechev.com/2017/09/16/developing-simple-interpreter-transpiler-compiler-tutorial/ https://depth-first.com/articles/2019/01/22/scanner-driven-parser-development/ - very concrete parsers, no abstract grammars

Comment: I think there is a problem with the approach here. You might think that `{p: "abc"}` can represent the html tag `<p>abc</p>`, but it doesn't. `{p: "abc"}` means `<object p="abc">`.

Comment: @sreginogemoh ... does the OP expect each of the provided solutions to come with a detailed explanation? Are 2 to 3 introducing sentences and readable code good enough?

Comment: @PeterSeliger yeah, that is file, forgot to mention that algorithm should be extensible in case if input data will be changed slightly

Comment: what happens to `h2`? please add a complete wanted result.

Comment: @NinaScholz all the `h2` becomes props names at some sort. `CTA message` +  `CTA button` => `cta: { message: '..', button: '...'}`. `Description` => `description: '..'`

Comment: this is an awful data structure with random keys and control data inside strings of data.

Comment: @NinaScholz that is right by I have no control over that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next provided approach features a generically implemented [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)r function which is custom configurable for ...

- an item's key upon which the creation of a new structured content type is decided.
- an object based lookup/map/index which features key based implementations for either creating or aggregating a (key specific) content type.

*From one of the OP's above comments ...*

> *"... forgot to mention that algorithm should be extensible in case if input data will be changed slightly –
> sreginogemoh"*

Though I wouldn't go that far naming the approach *"top-down parser"* as others already did, the parser analogy helps.

The advantage of the approach comes with the (generically implemented) reducer which roughly fulfills the task of a main tokenizer by processing an array/list from top to bottom (or left to right).

Upon a match of a custom provided property name (or `key`-word) and a currently processed item's (token's) sole entry's key the reducer does create a new structured (data) item. Non matching item-keys do signal an aggregation task.

Both task types (creation and aggregation) have in common that they too, always have to be custom implemented/provided as methods of an object based lookup/map/index.

The aggregation tasks can be manifold, depending on whether a to be merged sub content type gets hinted explicitly (by e.g. other specific entry-keys) or not. What they have in common is the passing of always the same arguments signature of `(predecessor, merger, key, value)`.

This four parameters present the sufficient information (neither less nor more data) it needs, in order to reliably aggregate any sub content type (based on `key`, `value` and if necessary on `predecessor`) at the base/main content type which was passed as `merger`.

***FYI** ... In terms of the top-down parser analogy one should notice that with the `predecessor` item/token one actually uses a top-down/lookbehind approach (but top-down from the little theory I know is supposed to come with lookahead).*

The reducer approach allows both the adaption to other source items and the creation of other target structures by changing the to be passed [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works_with_an_initial_value)'s properties ... `newItemKey` and `aggregators` ... accordingly.

The two folded solution of reducer and custom tasks got implemented in a way that the reducer does not mutate source items by making (actively) use of [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) for more complex sub contents whereas a task's arguments signature (passively) prevents the mutation of source items.

```js
// gnenerically implemented and custom configurable reducer.
function createAndAggregateStructuredContent(
  { aggregators = {}, miscsAggregationKey = 'miscs', newItemKey, result = [] },
  item, itemIdx, itemList,
) {
  const [itemKey, itemValue] = Object.entries(item)[0];
  const createOrAggregateContentType =
    aggregators[itemKey] ?? aggregators[miscsAggregationKey];

  if ('function' === typeof createOrAggregateContentType) {
    if (itemKey === newItemKey) {
      // create and collect a new content type.
      result
        .push(
          createOrAggregateContentType(itemValue)
        );
    } else {
      // aggregate an existing content type.
      createOrAggregateContentType(
        itemList[itemIdx - 1], // - predecessor item from provided list.
        result.slice(-1)[0],   // - currently aggregated content type.
        itemKey,
        itemValue,
      );
    }
  }
  return { aggregators, miscsAggregationKey, newItemKey, result };
}

// poor man's fallback for environments
// which do not support `structuredClone`.
const cloneDataStructure = (
  ('function' === typeof structuredClone) && structuredClone ||
  (value => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)))
);

// interface Content = {
//   title: string;
//   description: string;
//   content: any[];
//   cta: {
//     message: string;
//     button: string;
//   }
// }

// object based lookup/map/index for both
// content-type creation and aggregation
// according to the OP's `Content` interface.
const aggregators = {
  // creation.
  h1: value => ({ title: String(value) }),

  // aggregation.
  h2: (predecessor, merger, key, value) => {
    key = value.trim().toLowerCase();
    if ((key === 'description') || (key === 'content')) {
      merger[key] = null;
    } else if ((/^cta\s+message|button$/).test(key)) {
      merger.cta ??= {};
    }
  },
  // aggregation.
  miscs: (predecessor, merger, key, value) => {
    const contentType = String(predecessor.h2)
      .trim().toLowerCase();
    const ctaType = (/^cta\s+(message|button)$/)
      .exec(contentType)?.[1] ?? null;

    if ((contentType === 'description') && (merger.description === null)) {

      merger.description = String(value);

    } else if ((ctaType !== null) && ('cta' in merger)) {

      Object.assign(merger.cta, { [ ctaType ]: String(value) });

    } else if (value) {
      // fallback ...
      // ... default handling of various/varying non empty content.
      (merger.content ??= []).push({ [ key ]: cloneDataStructure(value) });
    }
  },
};

const content = 
  [ { h1 : 'This is title number 1'          } 
  , { h2 : 'Description'                     }
  , { p  : 'Description unique content text' }
  , { h2 : 'Content'                         }
  , { p  : 'Content unique text here 1'      }
  , { ul : [ 
           'string value 1',
           'string value 2'
       ]                       
  , } 
  , { p  : 'Content unique text here 2'      }
  , { h2 : 'CTA message'                     }
  , { p  : 'CTA message unique content here' }
  , { h2 : 'CTA button'                      }
  , { p  : 'CTA button unique content here'  }
  , { p  : ''                                }
  , { h1 : 'This is title number 2'          } 
  , { h2 : 'Description'                     }
  , { p  : 'Description unique content text' }
  , { h2 : 'Content'                         }
  , { p  : 'Content unique text here 1'      }
  , { h2 : 'CTA message'                     }
  , { p  : 'CTA message unique content here' }
  , { h2 : 'CTA button'                      }
  , { p  : 'CTA button unique content here'  }
  , { p  : ''                                }
  ];
const structuredContent = content
  .reduce(
    createAndAggregateStructuredContent, {
      aggregators,
      newItemKey: 'h1',
      result: [],
    },
  ).result;

console.log({ structuredContent, content });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

*FYI ... questions and approaches similar to the very topic here ...*

- [Transform array into object with custom properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72010046/transform-array-into-object-with-custom-properties)
- [Creating nested objects from a flat array of strings based on a number of specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71716982/creating-nested-objects-from-a-flat-array-of-strings-based-on-a-number-of-specif)

Answer (score 3):

As per my understanding we will have same format for each set of objects in the `content` array properties from top to bottom. If Yes, I just spent some time to work on this requirement and come up with this solution. I know we can optimize it little more to make it more dynamic. Can you please have a look and confirm if it works as per your expectation then I will work on the refactoring and code optimization part.

***Note :*** *All the steps has been mentioned as a descriptive comments in the below code snippet itself.*

Demo **:**

```js
    // Input Array
    const content = [
      { h1 : 'This is title number 1' },
      { h2 : 'Description' },
      { p  : 'Description unique content text' },
      { h2 : 'Content' },
      { p  : 'Content unique text here 1' },
      { ul : [ 
        'string value 1',
        'string value 2'
      ]},
      { p  : 'Content unique text here 2' },
      { h2 : 'CTA message' },
      { p  : 'CTA message unique content here' },
      { h2 : 'CTA button' },
      { p  : 'CTA button unique content here' },
      { p  : '' },
      { h1 : 'This is title number 2' },
      { h2 : 'Description' },
      { p  : 'Description unique content text' },
      { h2 : 'Content' },
      { p  : 'Content unique text here 1' },
      { h2 : 'CTA message' },
      { p  : 'CTA message unique content here' },
      { h2 : 'CTA button' },
      { p  : 'CTA button unique content here' },
      { p  : '' }
    ];

    // Variables
    const chunkEndIndexArr = []; // get the chunk ending index for each set of objects.
    const chunkArr = []; // This will contain the nested arrays containging each chunks. For ex: [[], []]
    let startIndex = 0; // This is the start index to loop through the content array.
    let splittedStr = []; // This variable is used to split the CTA message and CTA button strings which helps while building the final result.

    // Getting index to categorize the chunks seprately for each object based on the object { "p": ""} which is like a breakup for each objects.
    content.forEach(obj => {
      if (Object.hasOwn(obj, 'p') && !obj.p) {
        chunkEndIndexArr.push(content.indexOf(obj) - 1)
      }
    });

    // This set of code is used to create an array of each set of objects seperately which will help in building the algorithm.
    chunkEndIndexArr.forEach((elem, index) => {
      const innerArr = [];
      for (var i = startIndex; i <= chunkEndIndexArr[index]; i++) {
        innerArr.push(content[i])
      }
      // pushing each set of objects in a seperate array.
      chunkArr.push(innerArr);
      // resetting the startindex for the next set of records. 
      startIndex = chunkEndIndexArr[index] + 2
    });

    // This set of code is used to build the desired output from the chunked array of each set of objects.
    const res = chunkArr.map(chunk => {
      const innerObj = {};
      chunk.forEach(obj => {
        // Property assignment for Title
        if (Object.hasOwn(obj, 'h1')) {
          innerObj.title = obj.h1
        }
        // Property assignment for Description
        if (Object.hasOwn(obj, 'h2') && obj.h2 === 'Description') {
          innerObj[obj.h2.toLowerCase()] = Object.values(chunk[chunk.indexOf(obj) + 1])[0]
        }
        // Property assignment for Content
        if (Object.hasOwn(obj, 'h2') && obj.h2 === 'Content') {
          innerObj[obj.h2.toLowerCase()] = [];
          if (Object.hasOwn(chunk[chunk.indexOf(obj) + 1], 'p')) {
            innerObj[obj.h2.toLowerCase()].push(chunk[chunk.indexOf(obj) + 1])
          }
          if (Object.hasOwn(chunk[chunk.indexOf(obj) + 2], 'ul')) {
            innerObj[obj.h2.toLowerCase()].push(chunk[chunk.indexOf(obj) + 2])
          }
          if (Object.hasOwn(chunk[chunk.indexOf(obj) + 3], 'p') && chunk[chunk.indexOf(obj) + 3].p.includes('Content')) {
            innerObj[obj.h2.toLowerCase()].push(chunk[chunk.indexOf(obj) + 3])
          }
        }
        // Property assignment for CTA message.
        if (Object.hasOwn(obj, 'h2') && obj.h2.includes('CTA message')) {
          splittedStr = obj.h2.toLowerCase().split(' ');
          innerObj[splittedStr[0]] = {};
          innerObj[splittedStr[0]].message = Object.values(chunk[chunk.indexOf(obj) + 1])[0];
        }
        
        // Property assignment for CTA button.
        if (Object.hasOwn(obj, 'h2') && obj.h2.includes('CTA button')) {
          innerObj[splittedStr[0]].button = Object.values(chunk[chunk.indexOf(obj) + 1])[0];
        }
      });
      return innerObj;
    });

document.getElementById("result").innerText = JSON.stringify(res, null, 2); // Final result
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: give me about 24 hours to play with the code and come back on that with a proper comment

Comment: @sreginogemoh Sure!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working solution:

```js
const content = 
  [ { h1 : 'This is title number 1'          } 
  , { h2 : 'Description'                     }
  , { p  : 'Description unique content text' }
  , { h2 : 'Content'                         }
  , { p  : 'Content unique text here 1'      }
  , { ul : [ 
           'string value 1',
           'string value 2'
       ]                       
  , } 
  , { p  : 'Content unique text here 2'      }
  , { h2 : 'CTA message'                     }
  , { p  : 'CTA message unique content here' }
  , { h2 : 'CTA button'                      }
  , { p  : 'CTA button unique content here'  }
  , { p  : ''                                }
  , { h1 : 'This is title number 2'          } 
  , { h2 : 'Description'                     }
  , { p  : 'Description unique content text' }
  , { h2 : 'Content'                         }
  , { p  : 'Content unique text here 1'      }
  , { h2 : 'CTA message'                     }
  , { p  : 'CTA message unique content here' }
  , { h2 : 'CTA button'                      }
  , { p  : 'CTA button unique content here'  }
  , { p  : ''                                }
  ]


function getChunks (content){
   const chunks = {}
  let chunkIndex = -1
  content.forEach(entry=> {
    const entries = Object.entries(entry)[0]
    const key = entries[0]
     const value = entries[1]
    if(key=== "h1"){
      chunkIndex++
    }
    if(chunks[chunkIndex]){
       return chunks[chunkIndex].push({key, value})
    }
    return chunks[chunkIndex] = [{key, value}]
  })
  return Object.values(chunks)
}

function formatChunk(chunk){
   const interface = {
  title: "",
  description: "",
  content: [],
  cta: { message:"", button: "" }
}
    chunk.forEach(({key, value})=> {
     if(value.includes("CTA button")){
       interface.cta.button = value
       return
     }
     if(value.includes("CTA message")){
       interface.cta.message = value
       return
     }
     if(key==="h1"){
       interface.title = value
     }
     if(key==="h2"){
       interface.description=value
     }
     if(key==="ul" | key==="p"){
       interface.content.push({[key]:value})
     }
   })
  return interface
}

function parseObj(content){
  const chunks = getChunks(content)
  return chunks.map(chunk=> formatChunk(chunk))
}

console.log(parseObj(content))
```